# update value of attribute with foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql

If i'm trying to change the value of usertypeid attribute of 'askexpert' table with the following query:

```
UPDATE aura_users_logins SET user_types_id="some value" WHERE user_profiles_id="some value";
```

It throws the error:

```
foreign key constraint fails (`aura`.`askexpert`, CONSTRAINT 
fk_askexpert_aura_users_logins` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id `aura_users_logins_user_types_id`) 
REFERENCES `aura_users_logins` (`user_id`, `user_types_id`).
```

But I can change the Userid using the following query.

```
UPDATE aura_users_logins SET user_profiles_id="some value" WHERE uuser_profiles_id="some value";
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I can change the Userid using the following query

```
UPDATE aura_users_logins SET user_profiles_id
```

No, you don't. You're updating the `user_profiles_id` column.

If you really want to, do

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
```

first. Later set it back to `1` again.

Answer (score 1):

It will be good to have a look at your table structure, but it seems that your "askexpert" table has a foreign key to the "aura_users_logins" columns (`user_id`, `user_types_id`)

If you update the "user_types_id" column, the rows on "askexpert" won't have a valid reference.

If you want to update the value you should:

- Disable the foreign key
- Create a new row on "aura_users_logins" with the new values and then update "askexpert"

Answer (score 0):

As "aura_users_logins" has a foreign key "user_types_id", which is referring to the primary key of other table. so, you have to make sure that the other table contain the key as primary key, which you updating in the query.

```
UPDATE aura_users_logins SET user_types_id="some value" WHERE user_profiles_id="some value";
```

"some value" must be in other table as primary key.